# Selecting Max(date) from table that has multiple rows with similar information

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to select the latest status change in a table where all status changes are logged and inbetween two date parameters.

However it selects all rows returned and not within the date I specify.

```
    Declare 
@Rangefrom date,
@Rangetill date;

SET @rangefrom = DATEADD(day, -50, GETDATE()) 
SET @Rangetill = DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())

Select 
  a.Candidate
, a.Newstatus
, @rangefrom
, a.date
, @rangetill
, a.Consultant

From AppStatusHistory as A
WHERE newstatus = 'Working Compliant' OR newstatus = 'Registered Compliant'
AND A.Date BETWEEN @rangefrom AND  @Rangetill
AND A.Date = (select max(B.date)
                from AppStatusHistory AS B
                where B.Candidate = a.Candidate)
```

From my understanding this should select a.date = MAX(b.date) that is between @rangefrom and @rangetill.

Comment: Thanks, In this case adding the () changes the returned data completely (it returns nothing.) is this expected SQL  behavior ?

Comment: You have replaced your date values. @rangefrom should be DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())

Comment: I doubt this is doing what you think it is.  AND is process before OR.

Answer (score 1):

I think the query indeed does what you want, only that in your case @rangefrom >@rangeuntil so you might want to swap the values in the variable declaration.

Comment: Does the order of declaration matter in SQL? I did not think it did.

Comment: @A.Chandler -1 and would you give more  if I could.    rangeuntil is before rangefrom.   OR is processed first.

Answer (score 0):

`Where` condition Should be: `WHERE (newstatus = 'Working Compliant' OR newstatus = 'Registered Compliant)...`

You need to be careful with `OR`, missing the `()` for newstatus selecting condition. If you do not add that, the `OR` will return you more results.

Comment: Thanks, In this case adding the () changes the returned data completely (it returns nothing.) is this expected SQL behavior ?

Comment: if it returns nothing, then you should assume there is no record fits, but you can validate it :) Returning 0 record does not mean it is not a correct behavior, you cannot put equal sign between them.

Comment: When I look at the data (in the front end ui and with a "SELECT * FROM AppStatusHistory" I can see that what I think I am saying in this query is true or the data is there. Would it be safe to think I may be writing the Query incorrectly?